# How to pass command-line arguments in CTest at runtime

Tags: command-line, cmake, ctest

I'm using CTest and want to pass command-line arguments to the underlying tests at runtime. I know there are ways to hard code command-line arguments into the CMake/CTest script, but I want to specify the command-line arguments at runtime and have those arguments passed through CTest to the underlying test.

Is this even possible?

Comment: Did you end up finding a solution?

Comment: @simon No, I didn't

Comment: I've made a feature requrest to CMake here: https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/20470

Answer (score 9):

I've figured out a way to do it (using the [Fundamental theorem of software engineering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_software_engineering)). It's not as simple as I'd like, but here it is.

First, create a file **${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/RunTests.cmake** with the content

```
if(NOT DEFINED ENV{TESTS_ARGUMENTS})
    set(ENV{TESTS_ARGUMENTS} "--default-arguments")
endif()
execute_process(COMMAND ${TEST_EXECUTABLE} $ENV{TESTS_ARGUMENTS} RESULT_VARIABLE result)
if(NOT "${result}" STREQUAL "0")
    message(FATAL_ERROR "Test failed with return value '${result}'")
endif()
```

Then, when you add the test, use

```
add_test(
    NAME MyTest
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -DTEST_EXECUTABLE=$<TARGET_FILE:MyTest> -P ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/RunTests.cmake
)
```

Finally, you can run the test with custom arguments using

```sh
cmake -E env TESTS_ARGUMENTS="--custom-arguments" ctest
```

Note that if you use bash, you can simplify this to

```sh
TESTS_ARGUMENTS="--custom-arguments" ctest
```

There are some problems with this approach, e.g. it ignores the `WILL_FAIL` property of the tests. Of course I wish it could be as simple as calling `ctest -- --custom-arguments`, but, as the [Stones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Rolling_Stones) said, [You can't always get what you want](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jv9sDn_2XkI).

Comment: I've made a feature requrest to CMake here: https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/20470

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand what you want, but I still can give you a way to pass arguments to tests in CTest, at runtime.

I'll give you an example, with CTK (the Common Toolkit, https://github.com/commontk/CTK):

In the build dir (ex: CTK-build/CTK-build, it's a superbuild), if I run:  ('-V' for Verbose, and '-N' for View Mode only)

```
ctest -R ctkVTKDataSetArrayComboBoxTest1 -V -N
```

I get:

```
UpdateCTestConfiguration  from : /CTK-build/CTK-build/DartConfiguration.tcl
Parse Config file:/CTK-build/CTK-build/DartConfiguration.tcl
 Add coverage exclude regular expressions.
 Add coverage exclude: /CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/
 Add coverage exclude: .*/moc_.*
 Add coverage exclude: .*/ui_.*
 Add coverage exclude: .*/Testing/.*
 Add coverage exclude: .*/CMakeExternals/.*
 Add coverage exclude: ./ctkPixmapIconEngine.*
 Add coverage exclude: ./ctkIconEngine.*
UpdateCTestConfiguration  from :/CTK-build/CTK-build/DartConfiguration.tcl
Parse Config file:/CTK-build/CTK-build/DartConfiguration.tcl
Test project /CTK-build/CTK-build
Constructing a list of tests
Done constructing a list of tests

178: Test command: /CTK-build/CTK-build/bin/CTKVisualizationVTKWidgetsCppTests "ctkVTKDataSetArrayComboBoxTest1"
Labels: CTKVisualizationVTKWidgets
  Test #178: ctkVTKDataSetArrayComboBoxTest1

Total Tests: 1
```

You can copy-paste the "Test command" in your terminal:

```
/CTK-build/CTK-build/bin/CTKVisualizationVTKWidgetsCppTests "ctkVTKDataSetArrayComboBoxTest1"
```

And add the arguments, for example "-I" for interactive testing:

```
/CTK-build/CTK-build/bin/CTKVisualizationVTKWidgetsCppTests "ctkVTKDataSetArrayComboBoxTest1" "-I"
```

Tell me if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

matthieu's answer gave me the clue to get it to work for me.

For my code I did the following:

Type the command  `ctest -V -R TestMembraneCellCrypt -N` to get the output:

```
...
488: Test command: path/to/ctest/executable/TestMembraneCellCrypt
Labels: Continuous_project_ChasteMembrane
  Test #488: TestMembraneCellCrypt
...
```

Then I copied the `Test command` and provided the arguments there:

```
path/to/ctest/executable/TestMembraneCellCrypt -e 2 -em 5 -ct 10
```

I'll note that the package I'm using ([Chaste](https://chaste.cs.ox.ac.uk/trac)), is pretty large so there might be things going on that I don't know about.

Comment: This however doesn't execute the test in the exact same environment as ctest would, e.g. if environment variables have to be set.

Comment: Depends on how the CMakeLists.txt are written. In our project, the test command also contains setting the environment variables. This was done specifically to make ctest -N more useful.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with passing a number of test runs to the test.
If environment variable is set, then use value, otherwise use constant default value.

The trick is to use shell for running a test executable and use parameter expansion.

With

```
a=${VAR:-20}
```

shell will assign to "a" the value of VAR if VAR is set, otherwise it will assign it the default value 20 -- this can also be a result of an expression.

Snippet with CMake code is the following:

```
find_program(SHELL sh)

string(JOIN " " LIBFUZZER_OPTS
    -mutate_depth=20
    -runs=$\{RUNS:-${DEFAULT_RUNS_NUMBER}\}
    -artifact_prefix=${test_name}_
)
add_test(NAME ${test_name}
         COMMAND ${SHELL} -c "$<TARGET_FILE:${test_name}> ${LIBFUZZER_OPTS}"
)
```

Running a test with CTest:

```
$ RUNS=10 ctest -R luaL_gsub_test --verbose
<snipped>
1: Done 10 runs in 0 second(s)
```

By default the same number of runs is used:

```
$ ctest -R luaL_gsub_test --verbose
<snipped>
1: Done 5 runs in 0 second(s)
```

See [commit](https://github.com/ligurio/lua-c-api-tests/commit/8b863990123f8c750ec66187e44425e5e60f2345) that adds passing  a number of test runs to CTest.

It is worth to say, that there is an [issue](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/20470) in CMake, where people requests forwarding command-line arguments to test executables.