# How to force run a disabled test from ctest?

Tags: cmake, googletest, ctest

I have a c++ project that leverages cmake, ctest, and gtest.

One of my tests needs to be disabled for the purposes of regressions, but I would like to run it manually.

I disabled it by using the gtest trick of naming the test `DISABLED_test_name`.

When I try to run it, I see the following:

```
$ ctest -R aie2_210a_ddr_2kernel_ddr_gmio_bd_api.maize_xrt --verbose
UpdateCTestConfiguration  from :/scratch/bryanloz/aie_controller_hax/test/build/DartConfiguration.tcl
Parse Config file:/scratch/bryanloz/aie_controller_hax/test/build/DartConfiguration.tcl
UpdateCTestConfiguration  from :/scratch/bryanloz/aie_controller_hax/test/build/DartConfiguration.tcl
Parse Config file:/scratch/bryanloz/aie_controller_hax/test/build/DartConfiguration.tcl
Test project /scratch/bryanloz/aie_controller_hax/test/build
Constructing a list of tests
Done constructing a list of tests
Updating test list for fixtures
Added 0 tests to meet fixture requirements
Checking test dependency graph...
Checking test dependency graph end
test 8
    Start 8: aie2_210a_ddr_2kernel_ddr_gmio_bd_api.maize_xrt
1/1 Test #8: aie2_210a_ddr_2kernel_ddr_gmio_bd_api.maize_xrt ...***Not Run (Disabled)   0.00 sec
No tests were found!!!
```

How do I override this behavior?

Comment: Add the correct options to the `add_test` command? https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/main/docs/advanced.md#temporarily-enabling-disabled-tests

Comment: How do you add your tests to ctest?

Comment: @ixSci I use the CMake's GoogleTest module which provides the gtest_discover_tests macro: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/GoogleTest.html

Comment: As a quick workaround/hack you can locate a file named like `ProjectUnderTest[1]_tests.cmake` where your generated files are, open it, locate your test name there in line which looks something like this `set_tests_properties(YourTestName PROPERTIES DISABLED TRUE)` and change `TRUE` to `FALSE`.  This file is autogenerated so it will be reverted whenever the file containing `gtest_discover_tests` is changed (or cmake rerun). There have to be an easier and more robust way involving CTest script but I can't come up with the solution offhand, it needs verification.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`--gtest_also_run_disabled_tests`](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/main/docs/advanced.md#temporarily-enabling-disabled-tests). This command line flag forcibly runs all the DISABLED_ tests.

Note that if you have multiple disabled tests and you only want to enable one of them using the command line, you can combine this flag with `--gtest_filter`.

**Edit for CTest**:

I am not familiar with `CTest`, but apparently there is not an easy way to pass command-line arguments in CTest at runtime. Maybe you can use [this workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54675911/1383356) to do so, or find the executable and pass the argument to it directly [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49269123/1383356).

As an alternative to passing the command line argument, you can set the `GTEST_ALSO_RUN_DISABLED_TESTS` environment variable to a value other than 0. See [this](https://www.scivision.dev/cmake-ctest-set-environment-variable/).

Comment: ctest intercepts the command line args, and doesn't forward them to the executable (gtest main).

i.e.

This doesn't work:

ctest -R aie2_210a_ddr_2kernel_ddr_gmio_bd_api.maize_xrt --verbose --gtest_also_run_disabled_tests

Comment: @WilderField  I edited my answer with some suggestions.

Comment: If OP is using automatic capabilities of the test discovery of GoogleTest CMake module nothing described it this answer will help.

Comment: @Ari the ENV is my favorite option at the moment. Will try it tomorrow. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

There is no good solution for this. I will just rebuild the test executables when I need to test locally. I can also invoke the gtest executable directly from the appropriate work directory.

Even the suggested ENV is not respected in the CTest scenario:

```
GTEST_ALSO_RUN_DISABLED_TESTS=1 ctest --verbose -R aie2_210a_ddr_2kernel_ddr_gmio_bd_api.maize_xrt
UpdateCTestConfiguration  from :/scratch/bryanloz/aie_controller_hax/test/build/DartConfiguration.tcl
Parse Config file:/scratch/bryanloz/aie_controller_hax/test/build/DartConfiguration.tcl
UpdateCTestConfiguration  from :/scratch/bryanloz/aie_controller_hax/test/build/DartConfiguration.tcl
Parse Config file:/scratch/bryanloz/aie_controller_hax/test/build/DartConfiguration.tcl
Test project /scratch/bryanloz/aie_controller_hax/test/build
Constructing a list of tests
Done constructing a list of tests
Updating test list for fixtures
Added 0 tests to meet fixture requirements
Checking test dependency graph...
Checking test dependency graph end
test 9
    Start 9: aie2_210a_ddr_2kernel_ddr_gmio_bd_api.maize_xrt
1/1 Test #9: aie2_210a_ddr_2kernel_ddr_gmio_bd_api.maize_xrt ...***Not Run (Disabled)   0.00 sec
No tests were found!!!
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem is with ctest and not gtest. In fact, ctest will happily give the right arguments to gtest, but then refuse to actually call it.

My workaround: Run `ctest` with your selected arguments (i.e. `-R` and `-E`), but then add the `-V -N` options to get a verbose listing of the command that it *would* run if it could.  Then copy and paste that command line and just run it.

For example,

```
ctest -R MyClass -V -N

UpdateCTestConfiguration  from :/home/me/build/DartConfiguration.tcl
UpdateCTestConfiguration  from :/home/me/build/DartConfiguration.tcl
Test project /home/me/build
Constructing a list of tests
Done constructing a list of tests
Updating test list for fixtures
Added 0 tests to meet fixture requirements

198: Test command: /home/me/build/test/testMyClass "--gtest_filter=MyTest.DISABLED_SpeedTest" "--gtest_also_run_disabled_tests"
  Test #198: testMyClass.MyClass.SpeedTest (Disabled)

Total Tests: 1
```

Then copy and paste the test command:

```
/home/me/build/test/testMyClass "--gtest_filter=MyTest.DISABLED_SpeedTest" "--gtest_also_run_disabled_tests"
```

If you are really lazy, you can automate the cut and paste like this:

```
eval $(ctest -R MyClass-V -N | perl -ne 'if (/Test command: (.+)/) { print $1;}')
```